# Visualforce using javascript to rendered and update the value

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I wanted to make if value condition before is 'Others', then i update condition to 'Non GP' and it will make value in amount support 2 is 0 and ill impact to total amount, gp3 updated and gp3%updated like in js.

how to make it works? because, when i tried call onchange=calc() in inoputtext condition the js is not called.
and if i call calc() on action support (oncomplete=calc()) the console.log in js is running, but the html value is not changged.
example: total amount should be 190.000.000, because value of amount support before is 100,000.00 now is not rendered (0)
[image]
i really need your help guys, thankyou

```
    <apex:page id="pageId" standardController="Delivery_Order__c" extensions="DR_Diskonto" docType="html-5.0" sidebar="true" showChat="false" showHeader="true">
    <style>    
    #map {
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size:12px;
        line-height:normal !important;
        height:200px;        
        padding: 20px;
    }       
    .roundCornerCss{ 
        /* outer shadows  (note the rgba is red, green, blue, alpha) */
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); 
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 6px rgba(23, 69, 88, .5);
        
        /* rounded corners */
        -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
        -moz-border-radius: 7px; 
        border-radius: 7px;
        
        /* gradients */
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, 
        color-stop(0%, white), color-stop(15%, white), color-stop(100%, #D7E9F5)); 
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, white 0%, white 55%, #D5E4F3 130%); 
    }   
    .requiredLoaderBG{
        background-color: rgb(71,71,71);
        opacity:0.7;
        filter:alpha(opacity=70);
        background-image:url('{!$Resource.ajaxLoadGif}');
        background-position: center center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        height: 100%;
        left: 0;
        position: fixed;
        text-align: center;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    </style> 
    <apex:form id="mainFormId">
        <pbe:PageBlockTableEnhancerADV targetPbTableIds="tableDetail" pageSizeOptions="10,50,100,200" defaultPageSize="50" enableExport="false"/>
        <apex:pageMessages id="msgId"/>
        <apex:pageBlock id="pgBId" mode="inlineEdit" title="Update Diskonto for Delivery Request">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!lstDel}" var="a" id="tableDetail" align="top" width="100%">
                <apex:column headerValue="Name" width="8%">
                    <apex:outputLink id="ppId" value="/{!a.ID}">{!a.name}</apex:outputLink>
                    <apex:inputField id="sapid" value="{!a.SAP_ID__c}" style="visibility:hidden;display:none;"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Finance Support" width="5%">
                    <apex:inputField id="finsup" value="{!a.Finance_Support__c}" style="width:99%;" required="true">
                        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="tableDetail" immediate="false"/>
                        <script>
                        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
                            var financeSupport = document.getElementById('{!$Component.finsup}');
                            if (financeSupport.value === '') {
                                financeSupport.value = 'No';
                            }
                        });
                        </script>
                    </apex:inputField>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Support Type" width="5%">
                    <apex:inputField id="st" value="{!a.Support_type__c}" rendered="{!a.Finance_Support__c== 'Yes'}" style="width:99%;" />
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Condition" width="7%">
                    <apex:inputField id="conditions" value="{!a.Condition__c}" style="width:99%;" rendered="{!a.Finance_Support__c== 'Yes'}">
                        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="tableDetail" immediate="false" oncomplete="calc(this)"/> 
                    </apex:inputField>   
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Condition Note" width="7%">
                    <apex:inputField id="pic1" value="{!a.Condition_Note__c}" style="width:99%;" styleClass="conditionNote" rendered="{!a.Finance_Support__c== 'Yes' && a.Condition__c=='Others'}"/>
                </apex:column>
                <!-- 5-->
                <apex:column headerValue="Amount Support 1" width="7%">
                    <apex:inputField id="amountsup1" value="{!a.Amount_Support_1__c}" style="width:99%;" rendered="{!a.Finance_Support__c== 'Yes'}" onchange="calc(this)"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Amount Support 2" width="7%">
                    <apex:inputField id="amountsup2" value="{!a.Amount_Support_2__c}" style="width:99%;" rendered="{!a.Finance_Support__c== 'Yes' && a.Condition__c=='Others'}" onchange="calc(this)"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Total Amount Support" width="7%">
                    <apex:outputText value="{0, number, ###,##0.00}" rendered="{!a.Finance_Support__c== 'Yes'}">
                        <apex:param value="{!a.Total_Amount_Support__c}" />
                    </apex:outputText>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Informasi Paket" width="5%">
                    <apex:inputField id="xforwader" value="{!a.Informasi_Paket__c}" style="width:99%;" rendered="{!a.Finance_Support__c== 'Yes'}"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="GP3" width="5%">
                    <apex:outputText value="{!a.GP3__c }" style="width:99%;" rendered="{!a.Finance_Support__c== 'Yes'}" styleClass="GP3Value"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="GP3 Updated" width="5%">
                    <apex:outputText value="{0, number, ###,##0.00}" rendered="{!a.Finance_Support__c== 'Yes'}">
                        <apex:param value="{!a.GP3_Updated__c}" />
                    </apex:outputText>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="GP3% Updated" width="5%">
                    <apex:outputText value="{!a.GP3_Percentage_Updated__c }" style="width:99%;" rendered="{!a.Finance_Support__c== 'Yes'}"/>
                </apex:column>
                
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
            <div style="text-align:center; margin-top:10px;">
               <apex:commandButton value="Save" status="ajaxStatus" action="{!simpanData}" reRender="mainFormId,msgId" rendered="{!($Profile.Name='Finance' || $Profile.Name='System Administrator')}"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!back}" />
            </div>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:actionstatus startStyleClass="requiredLoaderBG" id="ajaxStatus" />  
    </apex:form>
        
  <script>    
    function calc(p) {
        var qua = parseInt(p.value);
        var row = p.parentNode.parentNode;
        var gp3Raw = row.cells[9].innerHTML;
        if (gp3Raw === null) {
            gp3Raw = '0';
        }
        var conditionField = row.cells[3].getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
        var condition = conditionField ? conditionField.value : '';
        if (condition !== 'Others') {
             row.cells[6].innerHTML = '0';
        }
        var amountSup1Raw = row.cells[5].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
        var inputElement = row.cells[6].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
        var amountSup2Raw = inputElement ? inputElement.value : '0';
                
        var amountSup1 = parseFloat(amountSup1Raw.replace(/\./g, ''));
        var amountSup2 = parseFloat(amountSup2Raw.replace(/\./g, ''));

        var totalAmountSupp = amountSup1 + amountSup2;
        console.log('gp3Raw: ' + gp3Raw);
        var regex = />(\d+)</;
        console.log('amountSup1: ' + amountSup1);
        console.log('amountSup2: ' + amountSup2);
       
        var match = regex.exec(gp3Raw);
        var gp3 = parseInt(match[1]); // Convert to an integer  
        
        console.log('gp3: ' + gp3);      
        console.log('totalAmountSupp: ' + totalAmountSupp);          
        row.cells[7].innerHTML = totalAmountSupp.toLocaleString();
        row.cells[10].innerHTML = (gp3 - totalAmountSupp).toLocaleString(); //Set GP3 Updated
        row.cells[11].innerHTML = ((gp3 - totalAmountSupp) / gp3).toFixed(2); //Set GP3% Updated
    }
    </script>

</apex:page>
```